# Load Function to HTML//Generate Random Words

Tags: javascript

I'm super stuck. I'm creating a hangman game for a class and I cannot get the words to generate and show in my HTML. We're required to have them show as underscores but I cannot get them to show in the HTML either. I've been able to get it to show in the console but not in my HTML.Any help would be appreciated or any assistance in troubleshooting.

please see the code.

```js
//horror movie titles selected to guess
var movieTitles = [
  "halloween",
  "suspiria",
  "audition",
  "hereditary",
  "the beyond",
  "the evil dead",
  "the blair witch project"
];

//letters already guessed
var guessedLetters = [];

var numOfLetters = [];

//randomly assigned variable
var movieToGuess = null;

//attempts left
var livesLeft = 8;

//games won
var wins = 0;

//games lost
var losses = 0;

  window.onload = function() {
  updateMovieToGuess();
};

var updateMovieToGuess = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfLetters.length; i++){
  numOfLetters[i] = "_".join(" ");
}


 var movieToGuess = movieTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieTitles.length)];

document.getElementById("movie-title").innerHTML = movieToGuess;

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Hangman</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="javascript/games.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC" rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
<p>Press any key to get started<span id='any-key'> </span> </p>
<p>Movie Title:<span id="movie-title"> </span> </p>
<p>Letters Guessed: <span id='letters'> </span> </p>
<p>Lives Remaining:<span id='lives-left'> </span> </p>
<p>Movies You've Survived:<span id='wins'> </span> </p>
<p>Movies You Died In:<span id='lost'> </span> </p>
<footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are setting the `innerHTML` to `movieToGuess` before you define `movieToGuess`

Comment: I've moved it but it didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. `querySelector` is looking for `<movie-title>` instead of `<span id="movie-title">`. To fix it, either use `getElementById` instead of `querySelector`, or change `movie-title` to `#movie-title`.
2. As [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) pointed out in a comment, you're using `movieToGuess` before you set it.

---

EDIT: I see you edited your question and its code after I answered it. You fixed problem #2 but not #1. Worse, you introduced a new problem: you now add the call to `updateMovieToGuess` via `window.onload` inside of `updateMovieToGuess` instead of at top level, so it never gets called (essentially, you've created a chicken-and-egg problem).

Comment: I switched querySelector to getElementById and changed the order of movieToGuess. It still isn't working for some reason.

Comment: @mba1592 See my addendum above.

Comment: Just saw, I'm going to re-add the changes I just made. I just removed the window.onload however it's just not working. Does the window.onload have to be in front of everything? Wouldn't it have to be after of the function?

Comment: @mba1592 It needs to be where it was when you originally posted your question.

Comment: Pretty sure it was in there when I posted it.. Maybe I'm missing something. I removed it form that function though

Comment: Even if I completely remove the window.onload it does not work.

Comment: @mba1592 You're not supposed to remove it. It needs to be there. What made you think you needed to remove it? The problem was that you moved it from the right place to the wrong place. Just put it back in the right place.

Comment: @mba1592 The code in your question looks fine as of your latest edit. What exactly is the problem now?

Comment: it just worked.. ugh, apologies. Thank you so much.